# Decode PHP Curl Script

Tags: php, curl, decode, urldecode

How Can I decode this php curl script: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=YWE1i4U7

It's got un-encoded characters here and there,  like the "t"s, the "v"s, etc.

Comment: what *legitimate* reason would you have for doing that? i think all of us here have seen stuff like that and know that it can't be anything good

Comment: it's a script that I bought and I want to edit a small part of it, but have no idea where to do this since the entire thing is encoded.  I can tell you what this script does if that makes this question more "legitimate"

Comment: i don't know if this is a right question to be asked here , i did up score it cause someone didn't read your comment :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert each `\x12` escaped character with [`hexdec`](http://php.net/hexdec) and [`chr`](http://php.net/chr). And to automate that a little with [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace).

```
 print preg_replace('/[\\\\]x(\w\w)/e', 'chr(hexdec("$1"))', $script);
```

Though that's only a partial "decoding". Won't make everything legible, nor will it likely leave the code in a working state.

Answer (score 1):

This builds on mario's very cool string replacement.

1. Save your file as `source.phps` - most servers will display this as PHP source code and will not execute it. (Check with your local web server admin to make sure .phps is enabled and safe).
2. In the same directory, create a file that's a decoder, I called mine `decode.php`. The contents:

`<?php`

`$phpsource = file_get_contents('source.phps');`

`highlight_string(str_replace(";",";\n", preg_replace('/[\\\\]x(\w\w)/e', 'chr(hexdec("$1"))', $phpsource)));`

`?>`

This is a basic step that makes the code a little bit more readable so you can see the PHP. It's still very ugly, as it obfuscates itself as much as it possibly can, but now you can see, with code-[highlighting](http://us.php.net/highlight_string) the various calls to `base64_decode` and `header` the script makes.

Comment: No reason to use the `.phps` extension really, it does nothing in your answer.

Comment: My rationale is that if you want to look at the original source color coded, PHP is doing that for you right there. It's not necessary, but it is instructive.

Comment: I get that but, without stating it, less experienced programmers may deduce that you can only highlight code if it comes from a `.phps` file.

Comment: If you feel my answer would benefit from a carefully worded warning about that, please feel free to edit and improve my answer.